# Use the return of a function

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and I have great problem understanding some of it. For example, I have this 'function' :

```
smstofre([], []).
smstofre([T|R], [X|Y] :- frword(T,X), smstofre(R,Y).
```

with the following 'database' :

```
frword(bjr,bonjour).
```

This is use to translate a poorly written French sentence into a correct one.
I use it like that :

```
?- smstofre([bjr],E).
E = [bonjour].
```

This is cool, but I want to create a 'function' that will take a simple string, split his word and send back the same result has the previous 'function'.
So for example :

```
?- translate('bjr cb ?', E).
```

should return :

```
E = [bonjour,combien,?].
```

I tried to use the swi-prolog's function atomic_list_concat to split the string and create a function that would do everything else, so I did that :

```
reduireFosse(E, F) :- atomic_list_concat(F,' ', E), smstofre(F, E).
```

and it just return false.

How to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your `reduireFosse/2` procedure should read:

```
reduireFosse(E, G) :- atomic_list_concat(F,' ', E), smstofre(F, G).
```

Note the second argument of the head of reduireFosse uses a new fresh variable `G` which is used in the second argument of smstofre.

And the second clause of `smstofre/2` should read:

```
smstofre([T|R], [X|Y]) :-
  (frword(T,W) -> X = W  ; X = T), smstofre(R,Y).
```

Here we use `->` to avoid leaving a choicepoint when the call to `frword/2` succeeds, and otherwise just returns the word as is.

Comment: Thank you ! Your version of reduireFosse work great, but for some reason, your version of smstofre return false. So I keep mine and It work great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a functionnal design with maplist :

```
frword(bjr, bonjour) :- !.
frword(cb, combien) :- !.
% for words not found, avoid if then else
frword(X, X).

smstofre(SMS, FRE) :-
    maplist(frword, SMS, FRE).

translate(SMS, FRE) :-
    atomic_list_concat(Tmp_In, ' ', SMS),
    smstofre(Tmp_In, Tmp_Out),
    % build a "french" sentence
    atomic_list_concat( Tmp_Out, ' ', FRE).
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know how to do that, it feel more like what I'm use to.